# ¿Cómo agregar filtro en Web Service ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, visual-studio-2015

He estado trabjando en un *Web Service*, aprendiendo que es lo que hace y cómo funciona y demás cosas.

Con algunos manuales y ejemplos de internet logré obtener que me muestre todos los datos que contiene una tabla "X" de SQL Server, pero apenas le doy Invocar, me arroja los datos, necesito que me arroje los datos segun dos criterios de búsqueda, es decir, mi *Web Service* no tiene filtros para que arroje los resultados, no me sale el cajón de buscar o algo así, como en algunos ejemplos que he visto.

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable consultaIndividualSUCIS()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        // return constr.Idoneidad_Funcionarios.Single(x=> x.name == lif_Nombre); // corregir esta linea de codigo esta mal
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    dt.TableName = "Idoneidad_Funcionarios";
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La tabla de `Idoneidad_Funcionarios` está compuestas por las siguientes columnas:

```
+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
| lif_Id | lif_Nombre | lif_Apellido | lif_Cedula |
+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la definición de tu servicio debes recibir los parámetros de búsqueda, según los resultados que esperas, modificar tu consulta agregando como condiciones esos parámetros y agregando el parámetro al `SQLCommand`:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable consultaIndividualSUCIS(int lif_Cedula)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        // return constr.Idoneidad_Funcionarios.Single(x=> x.name == lif_Nombre); // corregir esta linea de codigo esta mal
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios WHERE lif_Cedula = @lif_Cedula"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lif_Cedula", lif_Cedula);  // <-- Este es el parámetro de SQL que estás recibiendo cómo parámetro en tu método
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    dt.TableName = "Idoneidad_Funcionarios";
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A modo de ejemplo yo puse el campo de filtrado `lif_Cedula`, pero lo debes ajustar según los parámetros deseados.

Comment: Compadre es exactamente eso lo que quería obtener, muchísimas gracias por tu explicación me quedó claro que es lo que fallaba y como se debe hacer las cosas en este tema de webservice, es muy similar al ASP.NET Normal. 
Ahora tengo otro par de dudas, lo posteo en este mismo hilo? o es mejor crear uno nuevo?

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido :D Cualquier otra duda que haya surgido es preferible hacer otra pregunta para mantener la coherencia en preguntas y respuestas :)