# ¿por que no me aparece el resultado de un webservice en SOAP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, visual-studio-2015

Buen día,
tengo este Webservice que cuando lo invoco me devuelve el resultado en xmlns a pesar de que lo tengo "configurado" para que me duevuelva en SOAP:

```
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod (
    Action = "consultaIndividualSUCIS",
        RequestNamespace = "http://localhost:53680",
        ResponseNamespace = "http://localhost:53680",
        Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal,
        ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped
        )]

    public DataTable consultaIndividualSUCIS(int tipoId, int numId)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tipoCodigoEntidad,    Nombre,     estadoAutorizacion,     tipoIntermediario,  indicadorVinculado,     tipoIdEntidadVincula,   numIdEntidadVincula,    nombreEntidadVincula,   fechaVinculacion,   fechaDesvinculacion,    organismoAutorizado,    fechaIniAcreditacion,   fechaFinAcreditacion,   ramosAutorizados FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios WHERE tipoId = @tipoId AND numId = @numId"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoid", tipoId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numId", numId);

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        dt.TableName = "Idoneidad_Funcionarios";

                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Bro, ¿cómo invocas ese servicio? ¿podrías poner ese segmento de código?

Comment: Compa es el mismo método de la otra consulta que me colaboraste de filtros:

Comment: Aclaralo igual por favor.. no todos sabemos cual fue tu ultima consulta o de cual hablas...

Comment: Si compa, lo edité y agregue en el comentario cual es el Metodo, creo que es eso lo que me solicita Flxtr
la pregunta anterior fue https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73255/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-filtro-en-web-service-asp-net

Comment: no que hace el servicio, si no como lo llamas....

Comment: Eso es preciso lo que quisiera saber XD, osea ni idea, supongo que si se como se llama el servicio podría identificar de donde proviene el SOAP, que hace la petición del servicio?
yo le doy [Invocar] y aparece XD